# How can I execute commands or move to other tabs without first closing the terminal executed by `:term`?

Tags: terminal, user-commands, nvim

I've created a new terminal by executing `:tabnew +term`.

How can I execute other Vim commands or move to another tab without first closing the terminal (`:term`)?

Currently, all input is directed to terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neovim there's only one key combination not passed to the underlying terminal process. From `:h terminal-input`

> To send input, enter Terminal-mode using any command that would enter "insert mode" in a normal buffer, such as `i` or `:startinsert`. In this mode all keys except `<C-\><C-N>` are sent to the underlying program. Use `<C-\><C-N>` to return to normal-mode.

As alternative use `:h :tnoremap` or mouse click.

Also note that in Vim there's also `:h 'termwinkey'` which defaults to `<C-W>`, so normally pressing `<C-W>:` moves keyboard focus into the command-line. However, `'termwinkey'` is Vim-specific, while `<C-\><C-N>` is a universal combination to enter Normal mode in both Vim and Neovim.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed.

Comment: please mention that this is nvim specific (the help topic as well).